# How to run/terminate shell command when starting/finishing iOS tests?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, testing

I am trying to write an integration test for my iOS app & our API server. Both are in the same repo, so this test would prevent merging any changes that would break their ability to communicate.

The server team has created a bash script that I need to call to start a local copy of the API server. That script will run until it is terminated. How can I run that script when I run my iOS integration test? I can't put it as part of the build phase as the build will wait for it to terminate before it lets the build finish. I can't use `Process` directly in my tests to launch the script because that's only available on the Mac, not to iOS targets. Refactoring all my networking & model code to it's own framework that supports iOS & Mac targets would work, but that's a sizable refactor to do. Are there any other ways to run commands along with tests? I'm just using `XCTest` for all my tests.

Comment: Can you move the whole integration test into a wrapper script that first runs your server team's script and then the unit tests, e.g. using fastlane?

Comment: Never used Fastlane, and from a quick scan of it's site, it doesn't sound like something they support. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Fastlane has a `sh` command to run arbitrary things, but that's not what I meant. My suggestion was to write a shell script that does three things: 1) run your server script in the background and capture its PID. 2) run your tests. 3) kill the server script.

Comment: If this shell script is what runs the tests now, wouldn't that break Xcode integration? How would you run/see results in Xcode then?

Comment: Yes. But nevermind, I think you should be able to do this by adding Pre- and Post-Actions to your tests. Go to "Edit Scheme" and click the triangle next to the Test scheme to see these. The "Pre-Action" would be to start the server and write its PID to a temp file somewhere. In the Post-Action read that PID file and kill the server.

Comment: Perfect, the `pre-action` and `post-action` settings buried in the scheme was what I had been hoping for. Kinda annoying they are under the scheme as there are multiple schemes that run these tests. But better then nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I found a way to run scripts on test start & finish. You have to do it for the entire test target not the individual test cases.

You have to edit the scheme, expand the tests and add `pre-actions` & `post-actions`.

[image]

Comment: Hi @jamone, I found pre-actions only run before the 1st test case, the following tests will not trigger it.